# Can anyone explain me the difference between NET I/O vs BLOCK I/O in docker stats?

Tags: docker, networking, operating-system, virtual-machine, disk-io

I am getting the following stats for my redis while running `docker stats` command.

[image: docker stats output]

I want to  know about NET I/O and BLOCK I/O. I read few documentation they are saying about BLOCK I/O is something related to disk operation. But I am not sure what is this NET I/O. Can anyone help me here to know about these?

Comment: 1st google hit for "NET I/O": https://forums.docker.com/t/what-docker-stats-net-and-block-means/37357

Comment: for one of my container net i/o is drastically increasing upto 107GB rabbitmq container but block i/o is zero.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Block I/O stats**:
The amount of data the container has read to and written from block devices on the host.
In other words the amount of Bytes written/read from your container to the disk.

**Network I/O stats**:
The amount of data the container has sent and received over its network interface. Displays total bytes received (RX) and transmitted (TX).
In other words the amount of Bytes your container had sent/received over the network.

Also the official [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/#:%7E:text=its%20network%20interface-,BLOCK%20I%2FO,id%20against%20a%20Linux%20daemon.).